# Insert into MySQl database after reading csv file?

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
nohaelprince@uwaterloo.ca, 01-05-2014
nohaelprince@uwaterloo.ca, 01-05-2014
nohaelprince@uwaterloo.ca, 01-05-2014
nohaelprince@gmail.com, 01-05-2014
```

I need to read the above csv file and extract domain name and also the count of emails address by domain name and date as well. All these things I need to insert into MySQL database but somehow I am stuck how to insert into MySQL database after iterating the list I got.

Query will be like this:

```
INSERT INTO domains(domain_name, cnt, date_of_entry) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);
```

Below is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import fileinput
import csv
import os
import sys
import MySQLdb

from collections import defaultdict

lst = defaultdict(list)
d_lst = defaultdict(list)

# ======================== Defined Functions ======================
def get_file_path(filename):
    currentdirpath = os.getcwd()  
    # get current working directory path
    filepath = os.path.join(currentdirpath, filename)
    return filepath
# ===========================================================
def read_CSV(filepath):

   domain_list = []
   domain_date_list = []
   sorted_domain_list_bydate = defaultdict(list)

   with open(filepath, 'rb') as csvfile:
       reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

       for row in reader:
          # insert the 1st & 2nd column of the CSV file into a set called input_list
           email = row[0].strip().lower()
           date  = row[1].strip()

           domain_date_list.append([date, email[ email.find("@") : ]])
           domain_list.append(email[ email.find("@") : ])

   for k, v in domain_date_list: 
         sorted_domain_list_bydate[k].append(v)


   # remove duplicates from domain list
   domain_list = list(set(domain_list))

   return sorted_domain_list_bydate, domain_list
# ===========================================================
def update_DB(lst):

    # open a database connection
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                         user="root", # your username
                          passwd="abcdef1234", # your password
                          db="test") # name of the data base
    cur = db.cursor() 

    a = []
    for k, v in lst.items():
        # now what should I do here?
        # this is what I am confuse

    db.commit()
    db.close()
# ==========================================================

# ======================= main program =======================================
path = get_file_path('emails.csv') 
[lst, d_lst] = read_CSV(path) # read the input file
update_DB(lst) # insert data into domains table
```

I am confuse in `update_DB` method.

Comment: `lst` has sorted domain list by date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you have such a complicated program for a simple task. Lets start from the top:

1. You need to first organize your data correctly by domain, date and then count.

   ```
   import csv
   from collections import defuaultdict, Counter

   domain_counts = defaultdict(Counter)

   with open('somefile.csv') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f)
       for row in reader:
           domain_counts[row[0].split('@')[1].strip()][row[1]] += 1
   ```
2. Next, you need to insert each *row* correctly in the database:

   ```
   db = MySQLdb.connect(...)
   cur = db.cursor()

   q = 'INSERT INTO domains(domain_name, cnt, date_of_entry) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)'

   for domain, data in domain_counts.iteritems():
       for email_date, email_count in data.iteritems():
             cur.execute(q, (domain, email_count, email_date))
             db.commit()
   ```

---

As your dates are not being inserted correctly, try this updated query instead:

```
q = """INSERT INTO 
          domains(domain_name, cnt, date_of_entry)
          VALUES(%s, %s, STR_TO_DATE(%s, '%d-%m-%Y'))"""
```

Comment: It works fine but in my `date_of_entry` column I am seeing everything as like this `0000-00-00`? Do you know what might be the reason?

Comment: As of now my data type for `date_of_entry` column is `date` in MySQL. Do you think that's the problem? If yes, then what it should be?

Comment: That's the default date format for MySQL; so you need to convert the date to the proper format.

Comment: This is what I  got - TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Answer (score 0):

the read_csv function here is returning the sorteddomainlistbydate,and the domain_list (which is a list), used by the update_db function, that's where you do the insert.

your list just contains the domain names, while what it should for per pair of key vals should contain the domain name and the count
like

google.com,2

live.com,1

```
for k, v in lst.items():
     cur.execute("INSERT INTO domains(domain_name, cnt, date_of_entry) VALUES ('" + str(k) + "','" + str(v) + "','" + str(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))+"')")
```

Comment: Thanks Brij. I am getting this error somehow `cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects`

Comment: trivial, convert the k to str(k) and v to str(v)  

                                                                                                                        cur.execute("INSERT INTO domains(domain_name, cnt, date_of_entry) VALUES ('" + str(k) + "','" + str(v) + "','" + str(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))+"')")